# Double Field Index problem when upgrading Objectbox library

Tags: objectbox

I upgraded Objectbox from version **1.5** to the newest at the time of writing **2.3.1**.

When I first run the build with the newest version, I was told to remove the Index from double Variables, as it is not supported at the moment (how come?).

```
/**
* Before (working flawlessly on Objectbox version 1.5)
*/
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id(assignable = true) private long id;
    private String Name;
    private String Address;
    private String Name;
    private String Meta;
    @Index private Double Lat; 
    @Index private Double Lng;
}


/**
* After removing conflicting indexes (Objectbox version 2.3.1)
*/
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id(assignable = true) private long id;
    private String Name;
    private String Address;
    private String Name;
    private String Meta;
    private Double Lat; // removed @Index
    private Double Lng; // removed @Index
}
```

The Objectbox database (lib version 1.5) has already many entities saved into it and I really can not afford my users to loose them with such a (trivial) upgrade.

The code compiles successfully after removing the conflicting @Index on Lat, Lng, but as soon as Objectbox initializes its database I get the following RuntimeException.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.activity.MyApplication: 
 io.objectbox.exception.DbException: 
 Indexing of float and double is currently unavailable. Please remove the index on Property Lat (5, Double)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5743)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
```

Looking at the diff of the default.json file it seems like it has been successfully updated by Objectbox and the Indexes for Lat, Lng are not present any more.

[image]

What am I missing? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably too late: but try to rebuild (clean + build) your project.

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox thank you for the hint Uwe. I tried cleaning the project several times, including Invalidate Caches / Restart in Android Studio. Still getting the same runtime io.objectbox.exception.DbException. Any idea what else could be done?

Comment: Turns out that ObjectBox does not support removing `@Index` on a 2.x version for properties unsupported by `@Index` (float and double were allowed by accident). As a workaround you can remove the index while remaining at version 1.5. Then at some later point ship an update to 2.x.
I will raise this issue with the development team if there can be a change that allows to remove unsupported indexes without crashing.

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox removing the `@Index` as you suggested is not an option, as there is no guarantee that the user will make the update of the app. In this case, skipping an app update (definitely possible) and updating to an App directly with the 2.x version would cause the app to simply crash. As a result the only way out of this would be to stay at 1.5 version forever, and migrating data back to the SQLite database. It would be really appreciated if the development team would find an alternative (working) solution for this migration, since it is a very frequently used app. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, it was implied that you only would take the step to update to 2.x once we have this fixed.

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox if a fix is possible I would love to update. The reason I encountered the problem in the first place was because of trying to upgrade to 2.x. Thank you for your support! Looking forward to the updated version of ObjectBox. The performance is really impressive.

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox is there any timeline regarding when the fix will be addressed? Thank you for the support!

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't possibly say.

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox is there any issue open on github regarding this or should I create one?

Comment: Feel free to. We are already tracking this internally.

Comment: Hi @Uwe-ObjectBox, do you have any news on this issue?

Comment: GitHub issue: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/712